# docker stats shows zero memory usage even for running containers

Tags: java, docker, jvm

I have two containers ran by Docker Swarm:

```
# docker ps
CONTAINER ID        IMAGE                               COMMAND                  CREATED             STATUS              PORTS               NAMES
18f1e7d79f5b        default/image1:latest               "/bin/sh -c 'java ..."   12 hours ago        Up 12 hours                             image1.1.x56zz152kmqtqpxzle5nkbs8r
11d1f05fcff1        default/image2:latest               "java -cp /app/sca..."   13 hours ago        Up 13 hours                             image2.1.ljztzeeh8i5r6ebr3n4hcj45e

$ docker stats --no-stream
CONTAINER           CPU %               MEM USAGE / LIMIT   MEM %               NET I/O             BLOCK I/O           PIDS
18f1e7d79f5b        0.92%               0B / 0B             0.00%               648B / 0B           0B / 0B             0
11d1f05fcff1        0.91%               0B / 0B             0.00%               39.9MB / 26.9MB     51.2MB / 0B         0
```

Host OS is Debian Jessie. There are JVM applications in both containers. Why does `docker stats` show zero memory usage? Should I configure my Java apps somehow to be able to see memory usage in `docker stats`? Is there some other way to check memory usage?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It is quite possible that memory cgroup accounting is not enabled in your kernel (which is a [common problem](https://github.com/moby/moby/issues/18420) that others have hit as well over time on Debian/Ubuntu based installs).

Can you verify with `docker info` or the output from the daemon that you aren't seeing messages like the following, nicely summarized in this blog post: [Debian Jessie w/Docker](http://web.archive.org/web/20170625185736/https://awhitehatter.me/debian-jessie-wdocker/)? If so, the fix is also listed there, as well as in the GitHub issue I linked in the first sentence. There is also a section in the install documentation about [enabling cgroup memory accounting](https://docs.docker.com/engine/installation/linux/linux-postinstall/#your-kernel-does-not-support-cgroup-swap-limit-capabilities) although it only mentions Ubuntu and not Debian.

Answer (score 3):

I encountered the same issue on my Raspberry Pi. To resolve it, I added the following parameters to the `/boot/cmdline.txt` file: `cgroup_enable=cpuset cgroup_enable=memory cgroup_memory=1`.

Sources:

- https://github.com/docker/for-linux/issues/1112#issuecomment-699512425
- https://forums.raspberrypi.com//viewtopic.php?t=203128

Comment: Worked like a charm for me! Just tacked these onto the end of the file and rebooted my Pi and I started getting memory stats

Comment: When I added this to the file, it didn't work initially. But after a reboot (`sudo reboot`) of the raspberry pi I was able to read the Memory. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Ubuntu 20.04,

```
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX="cgroup_enable=memory swapaccount=1"
```

I had a same issue until I did not **removed** the oom-kill-disable from my yaml file.

```
        --memory=1500m \
   # --oom-kill-disable \
```

Comment: What yaml file?